# What's the difference between a Python Package and a folder that contains modules?

Tags: python

From what I understand a Python package is merely a folder that contains Python Modules (i.e. files), but also has the `__init__.py` file.

Is this file necessary if the modules are going to be imported locally, and why is it necessary to declare a module, since most of the code I have seen this file is just empty.

It seems unnecessarily complicated, what extra functionality does a blank file grant?

Comment: *"[...] what extra functionality does a blank file grant?"* It makes the folder a package.

Comment: @KlausD. ... but what is the point, when you can reference it the same anyway?

Comment: You can't import a folder but you can import a package.

Comment: Not sure about the exact reasoning but it is probably to prevent accidentally importing a `.py` file from any directory. You must explicitly specify it as a Python package by including the `__init__py`, even if it is empty.